# Privacy settings for Photos authorizationStatus always returns notDetermined

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, authorization, privacy

**Background**

I am trying to determine the status of Privacy settings for saving to Photos with the below code, targeting iOS 10 through to iOS 14.

However in the Simulator, no matter what Privacy settings are selected for the app, the “authorizationStatus” returned is always “notDetermined”.

I would have expected the Privacy settings “Add Photos Only” to have returned “authorized”, and “None” to have returned “denied”.

> ***Update***
>
> There seems to be an issue getting the Privacy status from
> `PHAccessLevel.addOnly`, whereas getting the Privacy status from
> `PHAccessLevel.readWrite` works correctly.
>
> Privacy status always shows as "notDetermined" for this:
>
> ```
> if #available(iOS 14, *) {
> PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: PHAccessLevel.addOnly) { _ in
> ```
>
> Privacy status shows expected result for this:
>
> ```
> if #available(iOS 14, *) {
> PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: PHAccessLevel.readWrite) { _ in
> ```
>
> But I have no clue as to why that is the case...

---

**Question**

Is this a quirk with the iOS simulator, or is there an issue with my code, and if so, how do I correct it?

---

**Code**

```
import Photos

func authorizationStatusPhotos() {

        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
             PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: PHAccessLevel.addOnly) { _ in

        switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() {

        case .notDetermined:
            print ("notDetermined")

        case .restricted:
            print ("restricted")

        case .denied:
            print ("denied")

        case .authorized:
            print ("authorized")

        case .limited:
            print ("limited")

        default:
            print ("default")

        }
    
        }

        }    

}
```

---

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Have you set ```Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description``` in info.plist file?

Comment: Yes, confirming that the Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description is set.

Comment: Okay. And have you got any request dialog ? If not you can request again by ```PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization```

Comment: The request dialogue displays as expected the first time Photos is called. But when checking on the second time, "notDetermined" is retuned. Not clear on how to request PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization.

Comment: delete your app in simulator and install it again, i think this will work

Comment: Did you try the same on the device?

Answer (score 2):

For those, who's still looking for an answer: you should get the authorization status with the same `PHAccessLevel` with which you requested the Photos autorization, e.g.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: PHAccessLevel.addOnly)
...
PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: .addOnly)
```

`PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` returns the status for read/write permission and is **deprecated** in iOS 15.